# MQTT Subscribe fail in simcom module A7672SA

Tags: mqtt, esp32, at-command, subscribe

I'm using the A7672SA module in a device, and the communication will be via MQTTS. I'm facing an issue with the subscribe functionality. I need to subscribe to 22 topics, but I can only manage to subscribe to 10 topics, and then I receive the error message "+CMQTTSUB: 0,22". The message exchange with the module is as follows:

- Send: AT+CMQTTSUBTOPIC=0,[size_topic],0
- Receive: >
- Send: topic/sub1
- Receive: OK
- I repeat this exchange 9 times because I observed it was the limit of CMQTTSUBTOPIC in the documentation.
- Send: AT+CMQTTSUB=0
- Receive: OK

However, when I try to subscribe to the next 10 topics, I'm unable to do so. I can write the names of the next 10 topics using "AT+CMQTTSUBTOPIC", but when I send "AT+CMQTTSUB=0", I still receive the same error "+CMQTTSUB: 0,22".

Could you please assist me with this issue?

I've already tried to subscribe to each topic individually, but when I reach the 11th topic, I encounter the same problem: "+CMQTTSUB: 0,22"...

The only way I managed to subscribe to more than 10 topics was by disabling the clean session, and after subscribing to 10 topics, starting another session and subscribing to 10 more...

Comment: Note that you don't have to use the GSM module's built in communication libraries. Just use it as a dumb data modem. ESP IDF supports [PPP dialup](https://components.espressif.com/components/espressif/esp_modem) (not for this specific GSM module, but it should be dead simple to add support to the existing drivers) and has an [MQTT library](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/mqtt.html) which I suspect to work _much_ better than the one in SIMCOM's firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, for ESP-IDF, the ideal approach would be to use PPP dial-up. However, I'm creating a generic library for AT communication with this module, and in this case, I'm using ESP32 just for communication testing purposes. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're encountering a limitation in the A7672SA module's MQTT subscription functionality. Unfortunately, this is a known issue with the module and can't be easily resolved. The module's documentation is incorrect regarding the maximum number of topics you can subscribe to.

To work around this limitation, you can try using a different MQTT library or switch to a different module that supports a higher number of topics for subscription. Another option would be to divide your topics into smaller groups and subscribe to them in batches, but this might not be ideal for your specific use case.